# Tesseract Unknown Font training

Tags: fonts, ocr, cad, python-tesseract

I have been trying to train Tesseract 4.0 to recognise "customized" font from an engineering blueprint.  I've followed the necessary steps using Training Tesseract from here -
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract-4.00

I've created a single tiff image from the blueprint page . I am able to create a box file and edit that box file using tesseract4java. The problem is after training all I get is a blank output.

Is it possible to train Tesseract directly from image file without giving initial Text file having the exact font?

Comment: very interested in a response also regaring version 3.05 of Tesseract